# i am not able to process all the records of a list through the executor's submit method

Tags: java, multithreading

Here in this piece of code, i am creating FixedThreadPool = 3, and in the for-loop, my list is carrying 7 records to be processed. For each record to be processed i am assigning its values to
msnsfExecutorThread Object that is Autowired at the top. After all the assignments, i am passing the msnsfExecutorThread Object to the submit method that expects a runnable implementation. Now, the issue in my case, is that whenever i reach the run method of msnsfExecutorThread object, it always possesses the details of the last record from the list. Its not working for all the 7 records of the list. How can it work for all the records from the list ?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (TempMSISDNCollectFee tempMSISDNCollectFee : list) {
    msnsfExecutorThread.setGcsAccountId(tempMSISDNCollectFee.getGcsAccountId());
    msnsfExecutorThread.setMsisdn(tempMSISDNCollectFee.getMsisdn());
    msnsfExecutorThread.setProcessStatus(tempMSISDNCollectFee.getProcessingStatus());
    msnsfExecutorThread.setPartnerCode(tempMSISDNCollectFee.getPartnerCode());
    executor.submit(msnsfExecutorThread);
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is your ```msnsfExecutorThread```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably not creating more than 1 msnsfExecutorThread object and keep overriding the data you set .use a concurrent data structure like a concurrentlinkedqueue, set this queue to each msnsfExecutorThread object you create. then in the run() method poll from queue and process.

Comment: Yes, i am using only a single instance of msnsfExecutorThread object. You mean i should add my list of TempMSISDNCollectFee to the concurrentlinkedqueue and then add that queue to this msnsfExecutorThread object ? @Fikret

Comment: yea, not saying this is the reason your app processes only last record but its good practice to use a queue rather than a list if you are writing multithreaded application. list is not thread safe.

Comment: Your solution helped.Thanks @Fikret